# Implement SAML SSO with Azure AD for desktop app(WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

How can I implement SAML SSO with Azure Active Directory for desktop app (WPF) ?

Currently I am making it work with the .NET Web API and OneLogin library, but what should be the Reply URL for desktop app that I should supply to AzureAD ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SAML does not really support web API.

Open ID Connect / OAuth is used for that. That's why Azure AD wants a redirect URI.

Why does it have to be SAML? Rather use the ADAL OWIN library.